# How to write to file in VSS from c# code?

Tags: c#, visual-sourcesafe

I have a project with Visual Source Safe (VSS) and I need to append lines to a ".sql" file.
I am trying to use the obvious code:

```
using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(lblSourceFile.Text))
{
    sw.WriteLine("text here");
}
```

But I am getting "File Access" error because the file is not checked out in the VSS.
Is there a way to programmaticlly check-out the file for edit and check it back in when finish ?
All links I found  are using VSSDatabaseClass, and I don't how to add reference for SourceSafetypelib dll and use VSSDatabaseClass...

Comment: as far as I remember there should be command line tool for that: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/asxkfzy4(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: I didn't find what i need there...

Comment: Do you need to checkout the file or just make it writeable?

Comment: I need to write something in it, so checking it out is probably a must, unless you know how I can write in it without checking out the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Rachel for the ssapi.dll file.
Here is the code that worked for my:

```
 using SourceSafeTypeLib;
 VSSDatabaseClass vssDatabase = new VSSDatabaseClass();
 vssDatabase.Open("VSS database path", "userName", "password");
 VSSItem item = vssDatabase.get_VSSItem("file path as shown in vss", false);
 item.Checkout("Comments", item.LocalSpec, 0);
 using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(lblSourceFile.Text))
 {
     sw.WriteLine("text");
 }
 item.Checkin("Comments", item.LocalSpec, 0);
 vssDatabase.Close();
```

Comment: was your "file path as shown in vss" the same as the lblSourceFile.Text?

Answer (score 1):

You can add ssapi.dll, which can be found in the installation folder of VSS, as reference and then you can use SourceSafetypelib. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/286713/how-to-get-a-file-from-sourcesafe-programmatically) you can see a sample.

Comment: Can you please tell me whre do I bring the ctor parameters from ?
`SourceSafeDatabase sourceControlDatabase = new SourceSafeDatabase("dbPath", "username", "password", "rootProject");`
I have my username ans pwd, but where do I get the other two: dbpath and rootProject ?

Comment: I got it: `using SourceSafeTypeLib;
 VSSDatabaseClass vssDatabase = new VSSDatabaseClass();
 vssDatabase.Open("VSS database path", "userName", "password");
 VSSItem item = vssDatabase.get_VSSItem("file path as shown in vss", false);
 item.Checkout("Comments", item.LocalSpec, 0);
 using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(lblSourceFile.Text))
 {
     sw.WriteLine("text");
 }
 item.Checkin("Comments", item.LocalSpec, 0);
 vssDatabase.Close();` thanks.